# Sync/Rendezvous point in VSTS 2013

Tags: performance, load-testing, visualstudio

Just to give background about the problem.

Few weeks back I started using VSTS Ultimate 2013 for Performance and Load testing (this is Client's demand to use only VSTS), earlier than that I have worked on other tools for the Performance and Load testing.

Now, we have to implement a Sync point known as **Rendezvous point** in VSTS performance tests (Rendezvous point is basically Load Runner term as far as I know).

> This Rendezvous point instruct virtual users to wait during test
> execution for multiple virtual users to arrive at a certain point, in
> order that they may simultaneously perform a task.

I have searched a lot and found that VSTS does not have this functionality as in built feature (not at least up to VSTS 2012). Reference [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3bf319bc-c4d8-4b96-b6ba-ad6b3fda1dce/how-can-we-put-rendezvous-point-in-vsts-2012) for the same.

I had found a [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140604204857/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/billbar/archive/2006/02/09/528649.aspx) which states that this kind of thing can be achieved only by writing code in VSTS, but this link also states that this is for Unit and Web test created in VSTS that are being used as Load test, whereas I am using [Record and playback](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/987255/Load-Test-in-Cloud-using-Visual-Studio-Ultimate) functionality *(similar to the process described in this link)* of VSTS Ultimate 2013 for Recording Web Performance test and then using them as Load tests. So, how this solution can work for me?

Any ideas on how I can achieve this thing in VSTS 2013 Ultimate and What I need to do for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can split your tests to scenarios according to where you want to rendezvous and set the timing (delay start on the second with the run time of the first) on the scenarios so the second wont start until the first finished.